# How to script search a specific row in incoming .CSV files

Tags: csv, batch-file

Which is the best way for me to search all `.csv` files in the folder `C:\csvtest` once per day?

Im only intrested in the row with the tagname ending with `.REG102` if it is `<=3000` and if so output it to a text file in the same location.

e.g. `matchedfilename msg (IDG00105--IDG00105) 2017_10_30_13_30_33.csv`
where `matchedfilename` is the name of the file where the successful entry was found.

`.csv` file content:

```
[Data]  
Tagname,TimeStamp,Value,DataQuality  
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG96,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,6774,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG97,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,1,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG98,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG99,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG100,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG101,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG102,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,3452,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG103,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,52,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG104,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good 
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG105,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,13824,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG106,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG107,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG108,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG109,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG110,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG111,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG112,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG113,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG114,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG115,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG116,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,6287,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG117,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG118,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,339,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG119,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,0,Good
IDG00105--IDG00105.REG120,2017-10-30 13:30:33.000,30629,Good
```

Comment: What identifies the specific row you are hoping to check? the only identifying thing I can find, unless you're looking for a specific line number is **`.REG102,`**

Comment: Correct. `.REG102` identifies the row and should be put in an output .txt file if the value column is less or equal to 3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your task correctly, the following may be of use:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "sD=C:\csvtest"
Set "fM=*.csv"
Set "sM=.REG102,"
Set "mV=3000"
Set "oF=output.txt"

If /I Not "%CD%"=="%sD%" CD/D "%sD%" 2>Nul||Exit/B
If Not Exist "%fM%" Exit/B
::If Exist "%oF%" Del "%oF%"

For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/L "%sM%" "%fM%"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=," %%C In ("%%~B"
) Do If "%%E" LEq "%mV%" (Set "nV=%%~nC"&Set "tV=%%~nD"
    Set "tV=!tV:-=_!"&Set "tV=!tV::=_!"
    >>"%oF%" Echo %%~nA msg (!nV:*:=!^) !tV: =_!%%~xA)
```

*You may optionally change the source directory, file mask, search mask, maximum value and output file on lines 4-8 as necessary. If you wish to write fresh to the output file each time the script runs, remove the first two characters from line `12`.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer but for some reason i can't get it to work.

Comment: Don't change my script above, you were only permitted to modify the values in lines `4` to `8` and optionally remove the **`::`** from line`12`. I've just created a few CSV's and tested them against your information and it output the data exactly as your question asks!

Comment: HI Compo! Thanks. I deleted everything and tried again and now it works just fine! One question though. Why is the output file content double?
`msg (IDG00105--IDG00105) 2017_10_30_13_30_33.csv msg (IDG00105--IDG00105) 2017_10_30_13_30_33
msg (IDG00117--IDG00117) 2017_10_31_09_00_19.csv msg (IDG00117--IDG00117) 2017_10_31_09_00_19`

Comment: In answer, I cannot say for sure, but a possibility is that the script should find every instance of `.REG102,` in each file. If you have more than one instance where the `Value` field is less than or equal to `3000` it will output them all, not just the first or last occurence. Another possibility is that you didn't delete the `output.txt` between tests, meaning that the output would be appended to a file containing the same data from a previous run thus doubling the number of occurences.

Comment: also, I've noticed that the output you're showing, e.g. `msg (IDG00105--IDG00105) 2017_10_30_13_30_33.csv`, does not match that provided by my solution and your question specification, `matchedfilename msg (IDG00105--IDG00105) 2017_10_30_13_30_33.csv`. I have additionally made a small change to my code above to move the file extension to the end of the output string.

Comment: Every file is named like this `msg (IDG00105--IDG00105) 2017_10_30_13_30_33` and the content in each file is like the one in my question. 

I dont know why `matchedfilename` was added. But the output file gives double lines with the same content. Its not because its not deleted from a previous test. Somehow the script sends the file name twice to the output file for each execution.

Comment: I deleted some content from your script and now it's only shoyign the file name once. thank you for your help. much appreciated!! 
`For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/L "%sM%" "%fM%"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=," %%C In ("%%~B"
) Do If "%%E" LEq "%mV%" >>"%oF%" Echo %%~nA`

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is with powershell:

```
powershell "import-csv data.csv| where {$_.Value -le 3000  -and $_.Value -gt 0}"
```

in pure batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in ("data.csv") do (
    set /a value=%%c
    if !value! LEQ 3000 if !value! GTR 0 (
       (echo(%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d)
    )
)
```